# Continue to the next loop in a foreachloop with another nested foreachloop

Tags: php, loops, foreach

I have 2 Foreach-Loops. One of them is nested inside the other, e.g.:

```
foreach(...){
    foreach(...){
        //if statement
    }
}
```

Within the inner loop I got an if statement and if this statement returns true I want to break the inner loop and continue with the next outter loop. Is there any way to realize this? "break 2; " won't work as I need to continue with the outter loop.

Comment: `continue 2;` should do the trick

Comment: _“"break 2; " won't work as I need to continue with the outter loop.”_ - well then don’t _say_ you want to break out of _two_ loops, if you don’t actually mean that …?

Comment: Just use `break;`, it works perfectly!

Comment: The question is ambiguous: you can either want to break the inner loop and continue _the execution of code_ (aka next line) **or** you can _continue_ to the next iteration of the outer loop.

Comment: Of course, the title is a _hint_. It's just the wording and maybe the lack of code after the 'if' that helps in the confusion, I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like with `break`, you can add a number to `continue` as well:

```
foreach(...) {
    foreach(...) {
        if (...)
            continue 2;
    }
    // this will be skipped
}
```

From the docs:

> continue accepts an optional numeric argument which tells it how many
>   levels of enclosing loops it should skip to the end of. The default
>   value is 1, thus skipping to the end of the current loop.

Comment: as I understand the question, the OP wants to both break the inner loop and continue the outer loop.. I'm guessing there's something after the inner foreach to be skipped..

Answer (score 0):

Per PHP [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php), the default is 1, which only breaks out of the immediately encapsulating control struct

> break ends execution of the current for, foreach, while, do-while or
>   switch structure.
>
> break accepts an optional numeric argument which tells it how many
>   nested enclosing structures are to be broken out of. The default value
>   is 1, only the immediate enclosing structure is broken out of.

For example, the below code:

```
<?php
foreach(array(1,2,3,4,5) as $num){
    foreach(array('a', 'b') as $char){
        if($char === 'b') {
            break;
        }
        echo $char;
    }
    echo $num;
}

// Result: a1a2a3a4a5
```

It breaks before it prints 'b', but continues with the loop to 5.

Comment: I don't get why someone would "-1" this answer !

Comment: @teeyo no rules in the jungle called answer section xD. (it's not my vote, btw)

Comment: @FirstOne haha it's a mad world, I mean the goal is to help find a solution not to fight over it ! Whatever...

Comment: @teeyo I added a comment in the question, as I think it's the cause of the 'massive' downvote in the answers xD